# Fill(DataTable) succeeds in testing, hangs in Production

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

I have a console batch application which includes a process that uses SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) to perform a simple SELECT on a table.

```
private DataTable getMyTable(string conStr)
    {
        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        StringBuilder bSql = new StringBuilder();
        bSql.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTable");
        bSql.AppendLine("WHERE LEN(IdString) > 0");                 
        try
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[conStr].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(bSql.ToString(), conn))
                {
                    adpt.Fill(tb);
                }

            }
            return tb;
        }          
        catch (SqlException sx)
        {
            throw sx;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This method is executed synchronously, and was run successfully in several test environments over many months of testing -- both when started from the command-line or started under control of an AutoSys job.

When moved into production, however, the process hung up -- at the Fill method as nearly as we can tell. Worse, instead of timing out, it apparently started spawning new request threads, and after a couple hours, had consumed more than 5 GB of memory on the application server. This affected other active applications, making me very unpopular. There was no exception thrown.

The Connection String is about as plain-vanilla as they come.

```
"data source=SERVER\INSTANCE;initial catalog=MyDB;integrated security=True;"
```

Apologies if I use the wrong terms regarding what the SQL DBA reported below, but when we had a trace put on the SQL Server, it showed the Application ID (under which the AutoSys job was running) being accepted as a valid login. The server then appeared to process the SELECT query. However, it never returned a response. Instead, it went into an "awaiting command" status. The request thread appeared to remain open for a few minutes, then disappeared.

The DBA said there was no sign of a deadlock, but that he would need to monitor in real time to determine whether there was blocking.

This only occurs in the production environment; in test environments, the SQL Servers always responded in under a second.

The AutoSys Application ID is not a new one -- it's been used for several years with other SQL Servers and had no issues. The DBA even ran the SELECT query manually on the production SQL server logged in as that ID, and it responded normally.

We've been unable to reproduce the problem in any non-production environment, and hesitate to run it in production without a server admin standing by to kill the process. Our security requirements limit my access to view server logs and processes, and I usually have to engage another specialist to look at them for me.

We need to solve this problem sooner or later. The amount of data we're looking at is currently only a few rows, but will increase over the next few months. From what's happening, my best guess is that it involves communication and/or security between the application server and the SQL server.

Any additional ideas or items to investigate are welcome. Thanks everyone.

Comment: With large databases it can take a long time to finish query in VS.  Do prevent hanging I use a BackGroundWorker to do work.  Instead of querying the datbase directly, I use cmd.exe which is a command line executable (comes with SQL Server) to perform query and produce a csv file with results.  Then read results into VS application.  I run cmd.exe from c# using a process class from inside a backgbroundworker.

Comment: @jdweng: I think that are some good points. if it is one simple select statement, run it from sql commandline tool exclude the possibility, that something is wrong inside the application. How large is the table? You could run the select with TOP 1000 to make sure, the result data is as expected. Writing data to csv first sound strange for me the first moment, but with realy large data it may be a way.

Comment: With my application the sqlcmd.exe was taking 30 minutes or longer on a 10GB database.  It was taking hours as a query in c#.  And my windows for application hung while the query was running.  The only method I found to get the results of sqlcmd.exe into c# was with a csv file.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It's probably not the size of the database or table. The application feeding it is in a "production pilot" stage, and there're only a few users. The table being queried has zero rows so far. In testing, the method worked correctly with the table containing anywhere from zero to several hundred rows. The production DB size is 5 GB, while the highest-level test DB we used is 11 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it may be caused by some strange permissions/ADO.NET issues as mentioned by [@user1895086](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288974/3745022), I'd nonetheless would recommend to recheck a few things one more time:

1. Ensure that queries run manually by DBA and executed in your App are the same  - either hardcode it or at least log just before running. It is better to be safe than sorry.
2. Try to select only few rows - it is always a good idea to not select the entire table if you can avoid it, and in our case `SELECT TOP 1`(or 100) query may not exhibit such problems. Perhaps there is just much more data than you think and ADO.Net just dutifully tries to load all those rows. Or perhaps not.
3. Try [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) to be sure that SqlDataAdapter does not cause any issues - yes, it uses the same DataAdapter [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbDataAdapter.cs,76ee69e4b70c4d1f), but we would at least exclude those additional operations from a list of suspects.
4. Try to get a hand on the dump with those 5 GB of memory - [analyzing memory dumps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production/) is not a trivial task, but it won't be too difficult to understand what is eating those hefty chunks of memory. Because I somehow doubt that ADO.NET will just spawn a lot of additional objects for no reason.

Comment: I accepted this answer because of the suggestion to compare the query the application was sending against what was received by the SQL Server. It was actually occurring in a method executed after the one above, and accessing a different DB with Entity Framework. A LINQ expression was supposed to cause EF to select, at most, a few hundred rows. Instead, the query it converted from LINQ was trying to load an entire 1.7 million row table into memory, AND doing it on 3 separate request threads.

Answer (score 1):

This may be tied to permissions.  SQL Server does some odd things instead of giving a proper error message sometimes.

My suggestion, and this might improve performance anyway, is to write a stored procedure on the server side that executes the select, and call the stored procedure.  This way, the DBA can ensure you have proper access to the stored procedure without allowing direct access to the table if for some reason that's being blocked, plus you should see a slight performance boost.

Comment: While I agree with nearly everything in here why do you think that a stored procedure is going to offer a performance boost over an ad hoc query?

Comment: That enters into a debate that rages between programmers and has for some time, especially now that the window is narrowed.  There was a time that it made a much bigger difference, but now it's more based on environment.  Still, using stored procedures typically boosts performance very slightly (as it seems to give the DBMS more freedom to optimize the query.  Why?  Reasons. I'm not a DBA) while preventing some pitfalls that can occur when using ad-hoc, and it also allows for changes to your query parameters without having to re-compile code and re-deploy to consumers.

Comment: It does not boost performance. An execution is compiled and cached for an ad hoc query the same as a stored procedure since sql 6.5 (nearly two decades ago). I am not saying I prefer ad hoc queries to stored procedures. On the contrary I am all in favor of stored procs and would never write my own ad hoc query, for most of the reasons you just mentioned. However, it is long running fallacy that a stored procedure is faster than an ad hoc query. It simply isn't true. Check out this article on stored procs. https://sqlperformance.com/2013/05/t-sql-queries/another-argument-for-stored-procedures.

Comment: I had thought about a stored procedure, since it forces the SQL server to do most of the work. The database is "owned" by another group (our application is trying to import data for reporting) and back in the design phase, I "sort of" implied a separate proc shouldn't be needed. I'm going to raise the idea, but everyone is out for the holidays, so it'll be a couple weeks before they respond.

Comment: Definitely push as hard as you can to use stored procedures. It gives your application a separation between layers. It makes debugging easier and if you do need to change the data logic you only have to deploy new stored procedure code.